# Как создать и прикрепить множественный обработчик для кнопок?JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите как сделать для двух кнопок один обработчик, хоть название метода, ато никак не могу найти.

Answer (score 2):

создаете handler и проставляете для 2х кнопок

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Button button1 = new Button("button1");
    Button button2 = new Button("button2");
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = event -> System.out.println("clicked");
    button1.setOnAction(handler);
    button2.setOnAction(handler);
}
```

Comment: А есть какой-то аналог в JavaFX методу onClick(View v) как в AndroidStudio?

Comment: есть метод `setOnMouseClicked` у Node

Comment: спасибо уже нашел)